# What is the function of the ‘dazu’ in this sentence?

Tags: expletiva

> Ich kann nicht glauben, dass ich mich von Ihnen **dazu** habe überreden lassen, mich freiwillig zu melden.

I understand the sentence to mean, "I can't believe I let you talk me into volunteering", but I don't really understand what the *dazu* is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *dazu* is the *into* of your English sentence.

While in English you

> *talk someone **into** something*,

in German it is

> *jemanden **zu** etwas überreden*

in your example, the "zu" is entirely optional, because you could rewrite the sentence to

> Ich habe mich überreden lassen, mich freiwillig zu melden.

In this specific example, the *dazu* simply works as an announcement of the infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. "dazu" is simply superfluous here, to say the least.
 "dazu" tends to be one of the words that are frequently misused in this and other ways.

For example:

> Ich habe mich zu den Wartenden dazugestellt.

A proper use is as back-reference, like so:

> Klaus hat mich überredet, **Chinesisch zu lernen**. Ich habe mich gern **dazu** überreden lassen, weil Klaus ein netter Kerl ist.